# Do not update with empty vars on UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run an sql update  but i dont want to update when the post vars that are empty.

Code that i run is :

```
require '../includes/db.php';
$settings_owner = ( isset($_POST[wb_owner_field]) ? $_POST[wb_owner_field] : false );
$settings_title = ( isset($_POST[wb_title_field]) ? $_POST[wb_title_field] : false );
$settings_description = ( isset($_POST[wb_descr_field]) ? $_POST[wb_descr_field] : false );
$settings_keywords = ( isset($_POST[wb_keywd_field]) ? $_POST[wb_keywd_field] : false );
$settings_id = ( isset($_POST[wb_id]) ? $_POST[wb_id] : false );

try {
    $sql = "UPDATE Website  SET  website_owner = '$settings_owner', website_title = '$settings_title', website_description = '$settings_description', website_keywords = '$settings_keywords' WHERE  _ID = '$settings_id'  ";

    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo a message to say the UPDATE succeeded
    echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Comment: You shouldn't enter the `try` if any of your post variables are empty. But you knew that already, right?

Comment: change `isset` to `empty`. `empty` does the same as `isset` but also checks if there is a value.

Comment: Based on your current code, something like this could work: `if(in_array(FALSE, array($settings_owner, $settings_title, $settings_description, $settings_keywords, $settings_id))){ /* No update */ }else{ /* Update */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to test the value in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Website  
    SET  website_owner = IF('$settings_owner' = '', website_owner, '$settings_owner'), 
        website_title = IF('$settings_title' = '', website_title, '$settings_title'), 
        website_description = IF('$settings_description' = '', website_description, '$settings_description'), 
        website_keywords = IF('$settings_keywords' = '',  website_keywords, '$settings_keywords')
    WHERE  _ID = '$settings_id'  ";
```

Another way is to build the `UPDATE` statement dynamically.

```
$sets = array();
if ($settings_owner != '') {
    $sets[] = "website_owner = '$settings_owner'";
}
if ($settings_title != '') {
    $sets[] = "website_title = '$settings_title'";
}
...
if (!empty($sets)) {
    $sql = "UPDATE Website SET " . implode(', ', $sets) . " WHERE _ID = '$settings_id'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much web programming, and haven't touched php in 10 years, but I  work with MySQL daily and would imagine something like this would work:

```
UPDATE Website  
SET website_owner = IF('$settings_owner'='', website_owner, '$settings_owner')
, website_title = IF('$settings_title'='',website_title, '$settings_title') 
, website_description = IF('$settings_description'='',website_description, '$settings_description') 
, website_keywords = IF('$settings_keywords'='',website_keywords, '$settings_keywords') 
WHERE  _ID = '$settings_id'
;
```